# Resolve into partial fractions, hence calculate the volume obtained

Tags: integration

Can someone please help me with this question?

a. Resolve $\frac{3x}{x^2-4}$ into partial fractions.

b. Hence calculate the volume obtained when the graph of y = $\frac{3}{x^2-4}$ is revolved around the y - axis between $x = 3$  and $x = 5$

I've resolved into partial fractions to get $\frac{3}{2(x+2)}$ + $\frac{3}{2(x-2)}$

I have an equation to calculate the volume when revolved around the y - axis but im not sure where to go from here when using partial fractions.

The volume equation is  Vy = $2\pi $$\int_a^b$ $xy$    $dx$

Comment: i use this formula$$V=\pi \int_{a}^{b}x^2|f'(x)|dx$$

Comment: Use $V=2\pi \int _3^5 \frac{3x }{x^2-4}dx$. You don't need to use partial fractions for this but if you must then integrate $\frac{3}{2 (x-2)}+\frac{3}{2 (x+2)}$

Comment: What method of integration could be used? I just took from the word "hence" in the question that it would need to be partial fractions.

Then  $y = $  $2\pi\  $x$ $ $\frac{3}{2}$$ln(x-2)$ + $\frac{3}{2}$$ln(x+2)$?

Comment: OK now evaluate from $3$ to $5$

Comment: you should get $3\pi  \ln  (21/5)\approx 13.5254$

Comment: Yeah thats the one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since we have $$f'(x)=-\frac{3(x^2+4)}{(x-2)^2(x+2)^2}$$ you have to compute
$$V=\pi \int_{3}^5x^2\cdot \frac{3(x^2+4)}{(x-2)^2(x+2)^2}dx$$
with your formula we have to solve
$$V=2\pi\int_3^5x\cdot \frac{3x}{x^2-4}dx$$
and use that $$\frac{3x^2}{x^2-4}=3-3\, \left( x+2 \right) ^{-1}+3\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{-1}$$
using the formula above we get $$2\,\pi\, \left( 6+3\,\ln  \left( 5 \right) -3\,\ln  \left( 7 \right) +
3\,\ln  \left( 3 \right)  \right) 
$$

Comment: Thanks but is there a simpler way to understand this? I will have to use the formula given to me. The way I've been taught is to resolve into partial fractions, then integrate using natural log.

Comment: i think your formula is not correct, may be a $'$ is missing, what do think?

Comment: I've never used a $'$ in an equation before what would that indicate? I have used the formula before with basic functions and it works, im just not sure how to use it with partial fractions.

Comment: which formula have you used?

Comment: For calculating the volume when revolved around the y axis:
V = $2\pi $$\int_a^b$ $xy$    $dx$

Comment: ok i will compare both results and here i will use your formula,ok?

Comment: Yes please, i have been given an answer I just cant follow the method yet

Comment: is this your answer as shown here?

Comment: The answer given when using the limits given for the volume is  13.53